# Error handling in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, restify

I'm creating an API using [Restify](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/) and [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), and I'm completely new to both. I can't seem to figure out the proper way to handle errors in Mongoose / Node.

As of now, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Submission.findById(req.params.submission_id, function(err, data) {

    if (err) 
        return next(err);

    res.send(data);

});
```

I'm attempting to call a GET on this (for a user that not exist). And rather than sending back a simple error message, it causes my entire node application to fail. I'm a bit confused on the user of return next(err) and what that exactly should do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `findById` query that doesn't find a match isn't an error at the Mongoose level, so you if you want it treated that way you have to do it yourself:

```
Submission.findById(req.params.submission_id, function(err, data) {

    if (err)
        return next(err);
    else if (!data)
        return next(new Error("User not found"));

    res.send(data);

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I'm looking for. Any thoughts on setting a status code (404) w/ something like that?

Comment: @NickParsons With Restify you can send a 404 error using buit-in errors.

The syntax is:

return next(new ResourceNotFoundError('User not found'));

More infos here: http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/#Error-handling

Hope it helps.